# cordova phonegap plugin push notification

Tags: cordova

I'm using phonegap plugin push notification, it's working fine, what i'm looking is to execute an alert as long as new notification is received.
for example:

```
push.on('notification', function(data) {
    alert('receive done');
})
```

so when i get new notification the alert doesn't pop up until no matter how long i surf the app, it doesn't show up until i click on the notification then after that it show up.
what i'm looking for is a way to make that alert to show up when ever a new notification is received without clicking on the notification.

Answer (score 0):

This is a big issue with push notifications on cordova. To handle the push right when you receive it, the push must be a silent/data only push. But if you want to notify your user you must use a local notification plugin. Unfortunately  depending on which two plugins you are using they may conflict. I have found that using [cordova-plugin-fcm](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm) works well with [cordova-plugin-local-notifications](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications).

With these you can handle silent/data only notifications immediately when they hit your device. The catch with the push plugin is that it does not show a notification on its own (if it is a silent/data push). You must use a local notification plugin if you want to handle receiving a push immediately while showing a notification to the user.

You can also check out my forks of the plugins (I have went through these same issues): [local notifications](https://github.com/DavidBriglio/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) and [fcm](https://github.com/DavidBriglio/cordova-plugin-fcm). The local notification fork gives added functionality to android, and the fcm plugin shows a push notification while also letting the application handle the push right when it gets it (no click needed) without the need for another notification plugin.

Either way you choose to go, you must format your push like so:

`{ "to":"[token]", "data":{ [data here] }, "priority":"high"}`

Make sure you **do not** have a "notification" entry in the json, or else you will  have the behaviour you are currently seeing.

Comment: ok thanks, but i don't really know how to make the push notifications silent/data only, and how to use a local notification plugin  to notify the user,   `FCMPlugin.onNotification(function(data){  what should i write here to notify the user that he received a notification using local notification plugin  }) ` . i hope you understand what i mean, thanks a lot

Comment: To make the push silent, you need to make sure there is no 'notification' attribute in the content of the push, and to set the priority as 'high' (my answer example is the format you should follow). Within the FCMPlugin.onNotifictation() method you should call the .schedule() function on the localnotification plugin you are using [here's the doc for that function](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/04.-Scheduling)

Comment: i tried your forks of this plugin 'cordova-plugin-fcm ' but it's not working anymore , whenever i get new notification i get that notification but the app stops it gives me 'Unfortunately, myappname has stopped.', i have another questions i hope you can tell me if it possible or not , i did post that question in here [My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46918330/cordova-push-notification-plugins-edit-a-div-after-receiving-a-notification)

Comment: it's not working on ios, when i send an silent/data push to my iPhone i don't get the notification at all, but when i add "notification" entry in the json i get the notification, on android i get the notification in both ways but on ios i don't get the notification if i remove the "notification" entry in the json.

Comment: Is this using my fork? If it is not than silent push will not be displayed.

Comment: i did fix that problem . i'm facing an other problem [my current problem ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47578913/phonegap-push-notification-subscribed-to-topic-but-cant-receive-notification-on) . thanks in advance